# setting ng-href in <tr> elements

Tags: angularjs

The following code makes the client.name an anchor on each client in clients. I am interested in having the entire `<tr>` element be that link however. `ng-href` does not work on the `<tr>` element.. what can I do so that the entire row is a single link instantiated by `ng-href`?

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <td><a ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">{{client.firstname}}</a></td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

What I am looking to do is something like this.. which of course does not work..

```
<a ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
    <tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
        <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</a>
```

OR

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
    <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your last approach should work.

Comment: only for give another option for you. I used the following: 

<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" 
ui-sref="user({tagid: client.tagid})"
>

In your route config you may have a route like that: url: '/user/:tagid', so. this can work for you too.

I hope this can help you in another time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use an [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick) (instead of onClick) as Jason suggests as well.

Something like:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-click="showClient(client)">
    <td><a ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">{{client.firstname}}</a></td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.showClient = function(client) {
  $location.path('#/user/' + client.tagid);
};
```

And styling to make it show as an clickable element (wont work in IE7)

**CSS**

```
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
// or
[ng-click] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Angular.js has a special handler for this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

Comment: ahh yes, I didn't even think to use it in this context. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer using a controller function, ng-click may not like what I was trying to do.

Comment: In the controller you should also use the $location service and $location.path('/user/' + client.tagid). This will let you use both html5 mode and hashbangs prefixed urls. Also if you really want to use window, try using the $window service which will give you flexibility for testing later on.

Comment: If you do not want to write the `showClient` function to every controller, you can use a directive like in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23699554/1878731

Comment: By doing this you're ignoring the default browser features like CTRL+Click and Middle-Click for opening in a new tab or Shift-Click for new window or Right-Click for Context menu ... I think this is a pretty bad solution

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a directive so that you can simply write:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" such-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
```

The source:

```
app.directive('suchHref', ['$location', function ($location) {
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      element.attr('style', 'cursor:pointer');
      element.on('click', function(){
        $location.url(attr.suchHref)
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Very useful. I used `$location.path()` instead because `url()` wouldn't work. Also, with `$location.path()`, the url must not include the leading `#` (it must start with `/`).

Comment: If you really want it to be a standard link so that "Open in new tab" etc. would work, you can use this directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344569/setting-ng-href-in-tr-elements/38234131#38234131

Answer (score 4):

I use my own Angular directive that automatically **wraps every cell in the row with a link**.

The advantages are:

- You don't duplicate code.
- There is a regular link in every cell so things like "Open in new tab" (middle button or CTRL+click) works as expected (in opposite of the ng-click version).

HTML usage:

```html
<tr row-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Directive code (in TypeSript):

```js
export class RowHrefDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService) {
    }

    restrict = "A";

    scope = {
        rowHref: "@rowHref"
    };

    link = (scope: Scope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes): void => {
        const cells = element.children("td[skip-href!='yes'],th[skip-href!='yes']");

        cells.addClass("cell-link");

        for (const cell of cells.toArray()) {
            const link = jQuery(`<a ng-href="{{ rowHref }}"></a>`);
            this.$compile(link)(scope);
            jQuery(cell).prepend(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Required CSS code (to fill the whole cell with the link):

```
td.cell-link,
th.cell-link {
    position: relative;
}

td.cell-link a,
th.cell-link a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Took me a while to adapt it to also work with `ui-sref`, but works great now. Thank you!!!

Comment: @qqilihq Do you mind sharing your adapted solution for ui-sref?

Answer (score 3):

This is a CSS and HTML issue, not specific to AngularJS. The only allowed child of a `<tr>` is a `<td>`, and so you need to wrap the content of each cell in an anchor. You also need to make the anchor a block element to make it the full height/width of its container:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
  <td>
    <a style="display: block;" ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
      {{client.firstname}}
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a style="display: block;" ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
      {{client.lastname}}
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a style="display: block;" ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
      {{client.inumber}}
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
    <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is with the referrence to the options provided which may work.
I think this binds the entire row with the each field in the row. but is not clickable. how to do that. i mean we should be able to click so that another view/module can be open.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @sfs, here’s the solution which we’re using for `ui-sref` (Angular 1.5; TypeScript code, apologies for any inconvenience).

**Credits:** The code is based on the awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234131) by [Martin Volek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2262449/martin-volek):

```
import { IDirective, IDirectiveFactory, ICompileService, forEach, element } from 'angular';

export default class RowUiSrefDirective implements IDirective {

  restrict = 'A';
  scope = { rowUiSref: '@rowUiSref' };

  constructor(private $compile: ICompileService) { }

  link = (scope, elm, attrs) => {
    if (elm[0].tagName !== 'TR') {
      throw new Error('This directive should only be used in <tr> elements.');
    }

    forEach(elm.children(), (cell) => {

      if (cell.attributes['skip-href'] && cell.attributes['skip-href'].value !== 'false') {
        return;
      }

      cell.className += ' cell-link';
      let link = element('<a ui-sref="{{rowUiSref}}"></a>');
      this.$compile(link)(scope);
      element(cell).prepend(link);
    });
  };

  static factory(): IDirectiveFactory {
    let directive = ($compile: ICompileService) => new RowUiSrefDirective($compile);
    directive.$inject = ['$compile'];
    return directive;
  };

}
```

Directive initialization:

```
import { module } from 'angular';
import RowUiSrefDirective from './rowUiSref';

module('app').directive('rowUiSref', RowUiSrefDirective.factory());
```

Example usage:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in itemController.items"
      row-ui-sref="state.item({itemId: '{{item.id}}'})">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.label}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

An ugly solution would be to just have 1 table cell which contains the link, then within that add another table with a table row and the other cells. So it would look like;

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <a ng-href="#/user/{{client.tagid}}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a>
</tr>
```

*I do not agree with using tables for layout!*

However, you are using JavaScript and angularjs, so you would be just as good adding a click event to the table row which sends the user to the url via `window.location` e.g.

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-click="ChangeLocation([yoururl])">    
    <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>    
</tr>
```

Then have a function within your `$scope` to handle this;

```
$scope.ChangeLocation = function(url){
    window.location = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for this...

HTML --->

`<ul ng-repeat ="item in itemList ">
  <li><a  data-ng-href="{{getUrl(item)}}">{{item.Name}}</a></li>
</ul>`

JS --->

`$scope.getUrl = function (item) {
        return '/<give your path here>/' + item.ID;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Martin Volek's Typescript code to make an AngularJS 1.x directive:

```
app.directive('rowHref', function ($compile)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr)
    {
      scope.rowHref=attr.rowHref;
      var cells = element.children("td");
      angular.forEach(cells, function (cell)
      {
        $(cell).addClass("cell-link");
        var newElem = angular.element('<a ng-href="{{ rowHref }}"></a>');
        $compile(newElem)(scope);
        $(cell).append(newElem);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Add his same HTML and CSS